# How to derive this Hicksian Demand?

Tags: microeconomics

So I have this utility function where I need to find t expenditure minimizing value of x. Normally, I would get the marginal utility of goods x and y, but doing that in this case doesn't leave any variables, so setting that equal to the prices would give me 2/5 = 3/3, which doesn't make sense. How do I solve this? I feel like I know how to do it but I'm just missing a major step or two.

[image]

Comment: Try drawing the indifference curve (for $u(x,y)=10$) and budget line.

Answer (score 1):

Since in this case, both utility function and the budget line are perfect substitutes and thus you can't equate the **Marginal Rate of Substitution** to **the price ratio**.

This problem can be solved this way,

$$\min_{x,y} \quad  3x+3y\\
    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \textrm{s.t.} \quad  2x+5y=10\\$$

or

$$\min_{x,y} \quad  x+y\\
    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \textrm{s.t.} \quad  2x+5y=10\\$$

Here,
     $$MRS=\frac{MU_{x}}{MU_{y}}=\frac{2}{5}<1=\frac{P_{x}}{P_{y}}$$ 
or,  $$\frac{MU_{x}}{P_{x}}=2 < 5 = \frac{MU_{y}}{P_{y}}$$

Therefore the expenditure is minimum when the consumer spends his entire income on good y, that is $(x,y)=(0,2)$ is the bundle that minimizes the expenditure given the utility $u(x,y)=2x+5y=10$. This is depicted in the figure below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The utility function shows that x and y are perfect complements with, y giving a MU of 5 and x giving an MU of 2. Both have the same price. Hence in equilibrium the consumer will consume only y. So quantity of x is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here,  Mux/Muy is less than Px/Py and this utility function is perfect substitute type So we are free to choose only x or y. 
Here the optimal solution will be(0, 2)